# "unknown column...ERROR no database selected" in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I've been trying to create a very simple view for my database yet I keep getting several errors. Here's the error I keep getting:

> unknown column 'nomorerack_base' in 'field list' ERROR no database selected.

This is what I entered...

```
SELECT `nomorerack_base`;
CREATE VIEW Category_Under_Five AS
    SELECT Sub_Category_Id, Sub_Category_name, Category_Category_Id
    FROM sub_category
WHERE Category_Category_Id<5;
```

nomorerack_base is my database, sub_category is my table. I checked the capitalization several times. I can't figure out what's wrong with the coding.

Previously I had entered

```
CREATE VIEW Category_Under_Five AS
    SELECT Sub_Category_Id, Sub_Category_name, Category_Category_Id
    FROM sub_category
WHERE Category_Category_Id<5;
```

and it kept saying error near line 3 (sub_category.... .

Comment: Place your code in code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` symbol. Or you can just add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line, but **don't use tabs**, they will mangle the formatting.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `USE` **db_name** instead of `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe how you're selecting the database name is wrong:

```
USE db1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;   # selects from db1.mytable
USE db2;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;   # selects from db2.mytable
```

[USE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just change from SELECT to USE.

```
USE nomorerack_base;
CREATE VIEW Category_Under_Five AS
    SELECT Sub_Category_Id, Sub_Category_name, Category_Category_Id
    FROM sub_category
    WHERE Category_Category_Id<5;
```